# Can't clear cache in Symfony

Tags: symfony, caching, size

My project symfony some to be more than 240 Mb (because of the cache).

When I try to delete them, they show to me this message in console:

```
[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
Failed to remove directory "C:\wamp\www\FirstProject\Symfony\app\cache\dev_
old\profiler\82".

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers]
```

Comment: try to do it manualy go to app/cache and delete all this folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove manually:

```
$ sudo rm -rf app/cache/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when running `SmartCore\Bundle\AcceleratorCacheBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache`
I had to stop Nginx and then it went through all right.